# Freeform Pro 4.1.3 and Google Event Tracking

Tags: solspace-freeform

I am trying to add Event Tracking to a FreeForm submit button so that when the user clicks the button it tracks the event in Google Analytics.

The problem I am running into is that regardless of how I try formatting the onClick event, it keeps getting stripped out.

Here's what I have tried:

```
{freeform:submit attr:class="btn btn--active" attr:value="Send" attr:data-ng-hide="formSent" attr:onClick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Contact', eventAction: 'Form', eventLabel: 'Project'});" }
```

And this:

```
{freeform:submit attr:class="btn btn--active" attr:value="Send" attr:data-ng-hide="formSent" attr:onclick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Contact', eventAction: 'Form', eventLabel: 'Project'});" }
```

Finally I just removed all of capitalization:

```
{freeform:submit attr:class="btn btn--active" attr:value="Send" attr:data-ng-hide="formSent" attr:onclick="ga('send', 'event', { eventcategory: 'contact', eventaction: 'form', eventlabel: 'project'});" }
```

## Regardless the outcome is always the same:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn--active" data-ng-hide="formSent">
```

As you can see, the onClick code is completely removed. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you considered making the GA call from jQuery on click?

Comment: No I haven't. I am not that skilled of a developer so I went for the easier route.

Answer (score 1):

As a work around you could consider [using jQuery with Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events), something like:

```
$('input').on('click', function() {
  ga('send', 'event', { eventcategory: 'contact', eventaction: 'form', eventlabel: 'project'});
});
```